# Unable to install gRPC for go in mac os

Tags: go, grpc

While running:

```
brew install
```

I am receiving:

```
brew command not found
```

and while running:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

I am receiving:

```
go: found github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go in github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2
go: google.golang.org/protobuf upgrade => v1.25.0
go: updating go.sum: open /usr/local/go/src/go.sum: permission denied
ksetti-mac-mini-4@KSETTis-Mini src % go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
go: found github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go in github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2
go: google.golang.org/protobuf upgrade => v1.25.0
go: updating go.sum: open /usr/local/go/src/go.sum: permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a lot wrong. 1) You're trying to run `brew install` without telling it what to install. Next, 2) you just need to read the error message to conclude that ***you don't have `brew` installed***.  And finally, a slightly more nuanced problem, 3) your user doesn't have privileges to write where it's trying to write (which seems to be a global go installation location, aka GOROOT). This leads to the conclusion that 4) you're either running an extremely outdated version of go (since go 1.8, from 2017), or you have configured your GOPATH to be your GOROOT, which can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `GOPATH` set to something like '~/go'?  It's trying to write to  a soure directory that you don't seem to have access to.

This is from my .bashrc

```
# GoLang Configurations
export GOPATH=$HOME/Golang
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```